# HTML frameset not loading properly second time in IE11

Tags: html, frameset

I have a HTML page with `frameset` is loading perfectly selected record in table in IE11. If I go back to previous page, select second record to open is not reloading with the selected data (showing previously opened data). No `js` issues in IE console.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
   <FRAMESET rows="98,35," frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
      <FRAME scrolling="no" src="explorerHead.jsp" name="headFrame" noresize>
      <FRAME scrolling="no" src="submenu.jsp" name="menuFrame" noresize>
      <FRAMESET id="parentFrameSet" rows=",85%" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
         <FRAME src="buttonHead.jsp" name="buttonFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" noresize>
         <FRAME src="tableBody.jsp" name="browseFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" noresize>
      </FRAMESET>
   </FRAMESET>
</html>
```

If I open developer tools(F12),it is working fine: no issues.
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some code ? then i can help you

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<FRAMESET rows="98,35,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
 <FRAME scrolling="no" src="explorerHead.jsp" name="headFrame" noresize>
 <FRAME scrolling="no" src="submenu.jsp" name="menuFrame"
  noresize>
  <FRAMESET id="parentFrameSet" rows="*,85%" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
       <FRAME src="buttonHead.jsp" name="buttonFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" noresize>
       <FRAME src="tableBody.jsp" name="browseFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" noresize>
  </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</html>